# Compact simple group which is not a Lie group

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, topological-groups, simple-groups

What is an example of compact topological group $ G $ which is abstractly simple ($ G $ has no proper nontrivial normal subgroups) but is not a Lie group?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $G$ be a compact simple group. Since the connected component $G_0$ of the group $G$ is normal, either $G_0=1$ or $G_0=G$. If $G_0=1$, then $G$ is a totally disconnected group  and hence has any small open normal subgroups. So $G$ is finite.

If $G_0=G$, then $G$ is connected and by the Gleason-Yamabe theorem there exists a normal subgroup $H$ such that the factor $G/H$ is a Lie group. Then $G$ is a Lie group.

Thus a compact simple group is either finite or a connected Lie group.

Comment: Does this argument still work if $ G $ is quasisimple ( i.e. $ G $ is perfect and $ G/Z(G) $ is simple)?

Comment: could there be some weird counterexample that is a perfect extension of a compact connected simple Lie group by a central solenoid/protorus?

Comment: Your question from the first comment is very interesting. I will think about it. The counterexample from the second comment I think I saw somewhere. I will try to look for it. I may be wrong, though.

Comment: It's not due to Gleason-Yamabe for $G$ compact, but to Peter-Weyl 25 years earlier (Edit: Qiaochu Yuan noticed this too).

Answer (score 10):

kabenyuk's answer is correct but we don't have to appeal to the Gleason-Yamabe theorem. By the [Peter-Weyl theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter%E2%80%93Weyl_theorem) a compact (Hausdorff) group $G$ has the property that its finite-dimensional unitary representations separate points; in particular if $G$ is nontrivial it admits a continuous homomorphism $\rho : G \to U(n)$ with nontrivial image. So if $G$ is simple (or even just topologically simple) it is a closed subgroup of $U(n)$ for some $n$ and so must be a Lie group by the closed subgroup theorem.

(Abstractly, pushing this argument a little further shows that compact (Hausdorff) groups are pro-(compact Lie).)